# PHP: Verifying that requests originate from Office for the web by using proof keys

Tags: php, ms-wopi, office-online-server

I'm trying to [Verifying that requests originate from Office for the web by using proof keys](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scenarios/proofkeys.html)

I have read this resource many times but still do not know how to implement it in PHP.

I tried the code below it didn't seem to solve the problem, I do not know what to do next.

Can someone give me a suggestion?

```
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$modulus = new Math_BigInteger(base64_decode($modulus), 256);
$exponent = new Math_BigInteger(base64_decode($exponent), 256);

$rsa->loadKey(array('n' => $modulus, 'e' => $exponent));
$rsa->setPublicKey();
$publicKey = $rsa->getPublicKey();
```

Answer (score 3):

I understand that verifying WOPI proof key is quite complicated to implement while extracting programming logic from their explanation in the document is challenging.
Unfortunately, I'm not a PHP developer. However, I'd like to share my production C# code in case it could help.

```
private async Task<bool> ValidateWopiProof(HttpContext context)
{
    // Make sure the request has the correct headers
    if (!context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey(WopiRequestHeader.PROOF) ||
        !context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey(WopiRequestHeader.TIME_STAMP))
        return false;

    // TimestampOlderThan20Min
    var timeStamp = long.Parse(context.Request.Headers[WopiRequestHeader.TIME_STAMP].ToString());
    var timeStampDateTime = new DateTime(timeStamp, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    if ((DateTime.UtcNow - timeStampDateTime).TotalMinutes > 20)
        return false;

    // Set the requested proof values
    var requestProof = context.Request.Headers[WopiRequestHeader.PROOF];
    var requestProofOld = String.Empty;
    if (context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey(WopiRequestHeader.PROOF_OLD))
        requestProofOld = context.Request.Headers[WopiRequestHeader.PROOF_OLD];

    // Get the WOPI proof info from Wopi discovery
    var wopiProofPublicKey = await _wopiDiscovery.GetWopiProof();

    // Encode the values into bytes
    var accessTokenBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(context.Request.Query["access_token"].ToString());

    var hostUrl = GetAbsolouteUrl(context);
    var hostUrlBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hostUrl.ToUpperInvariant());

    var timeStampBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToInt64(context.Request.Headers[WopiRequestHeader.TIME_STAMP])).Reverse().ToArray();

    // Build expected proof
    List<byte> expected = new List<byte>(
        4 + accessTokenBytes.Length +
        4 + hostUrlBytes.Length +
        4 + timeStampBytes.Length);

    // Add the values to the expected variable
    expected.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(accessTokenBytes.Length).Reverse().ToArray());
    expected.AddRange(accessTokenBytes);
    expected.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(hostUrlBytes.Length).Reverse().ToArray());
    expected.AddRange(hostUrlBytes);
    expected.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(timeStampBytes.Length).Reverse().ToArray());
    expected.AddRange(timeStampBytes);
    byte[] expectedBytes = expected.ToArray();

    return (VerifyProofKeys(expectedBytes, requestProof, wopiProofPublicKey.Value) ||
        VerifyProofKeys(expectedBytes, requestProofOld, wopiProofPublicKey.Value) ||
        VerifyProofKeys(expectedBytes, requestProof, wopiProofPublicKey.OldValue));
}

private string GetAbsolouteUrl(HttpContext context)
{
    var url = $"{_wopiUrlService.ApiAddress.TrimEnd('/')}{context.Request.Path}{context.Request.QueryString}";
    return url.Replace(":44300", "").Replace(":443", "");
}

private bool VerifyProofKeys(byte[] expectedProof, string proofFromRequest, string discoPublicKey)
{
    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        try
        {
            rsaProvider.ImportCspBlob(Convert.FromBase64String(discoPublicKey));
            return rsaProvider.VerifyData(expectedProof, "SHA256", Convert.FromBase64String(proofFromRequest));
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (CryptographicException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation follows [the document](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scenarios/proofkeys.html) spec. For the method `_wopiDiscovery.GetWopiProof()`, I just get `proof-key` section from [Wopi Discovery](https://ffc-onenote.officeapps.live.com/hosting/discovery).

[image: getting wopi proof key in wopi discovery].

Comment: you are a life saver... this code worked like a charm many thanks to you it has helped me a lot.

Comment: In the end, I finally made a PHP service that does it properly, you can find it here: https://github.com/Champs-Libres/wopi-lib/blob/master/src/Service/WopiProofValidator.php

Answer (score 0):

@Rachanee is your solution working? I have the same code but validation is failing.

Comment: Sure, It's working. I'm using this code in our Live environment.

Comment: Ah, I see. You have made it work re your comment below. Thanks for letting me know that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a WOPI Proof Validator in PHP, in this package: https://github.com/Champs-Libres/wopi-lib/

This package is a helper for integrating WOPI protocol in PHP applications.

It contains a WOPI Proof Validator service that you can use out of the box.